# jquery load page with switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's me again!!

Now.. i don't know what i'm doing wrong with this Switch Case... can help me?

When i click in some LINK, the alert dont apear...

this is my HTML:

```
    <div class="menu-site">
        <ul class="topo-menu" id="topo-menu">
            <li id="aabruzzo">a abruzzo</li>
            <li id="catalogo">catálogo</li>
            <li id="conceito">conceito inverno</li>
            <li id="representantes">representantes</li>
            <li id="clipping">clipping</li>
            <li id="loja">loja</li>
            <li id="contato" class="sem-right">contato</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


        var sections = $("#topo-menu li");
        var loading = $("#loading"); 
        var content = $("#content");

        sections.click(function(){
            switch(this.id){
                case 'aabruzzo':
                    alert("teste");
                    break;
                case "catalogo":
                    alert("teste");
                    break;
                case "conceito":
                    alert("teste");
                    break;
                case "representantes":
                    alert("teste"););
                    break;
                case "clipping":
                    alert("teste");
                    break;
                case "loja":
                    alert("teste");
                    break;
                case "contato":
                    alert("teste");
                    break;                        
                default:
                    hideLoading();
                    break;
            }
            });
```

i have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Cqt/)

Comment: @Alex K. found some errors, check his answer and if you want an updated jsFiddle, you can find it here http://jsfiddle.net/D2Cqt/7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ditch the `#` in the `id` here: (its jquery notation and not a legal `id` start character);

```
<ul class="topo-menu" id="#topo-menu">
```

and fix the extra `);` here:

```
alert("teste"););
```

You also look for case `"aabruzzo"` but the `id` is `"aabruzo"` (in your fiddle)

Comment: He missed some other things aswell. Upvoted, and here's an updated, fixed, jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D2Cqt/7/

Comment: yeah.. i see this after i post the jsFiddle link. But still not working on my page. my javascritp is in external file, this influence on something??

Comment: Possibly, you would need to provide the url

Comment: and my menu is in external page too... i load this with .load()

Comment: the problem is on my external page with menu... i solve this putting the menu on same page with script. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`this.id` should be `this.attr('id')` because this is a jQuery object.

Comment: No it's not - `this` is the actual DOM element. If you want to use jQuery functions with it, you need to wrap it in a jQuery object using `$(this)`.